# How to see source code of particular class in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to see source for particular class. For example, now I work with JUnit and in code have this line:

```
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(MyClassTest.class);
```

I want to see how is implemented Result class. Is it possible?

I imported JUnit jar into build path.
I am using Eclipse 3.6 Helios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways:

- download the sources and add them to the project build path
- use maven and set it to download sources
- use a decompiler - for example JD-Eclipse

Comment: I don't know maven. I installed JD-Eclipse and it work. When I do right click on class Result, end select Open Declaration it gives me source. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach source of the corresponding library.

Download Junit's source zip ( from their release site, corresponding to the JUNIT you are using) - [example link](https://github.com/downloads/KentBeck/junit/junit4.9b1.zip)

Then follow these steps in [IBM's link on the topic](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-115.htm) - with steps

Once you do that, Ctrl + click on the class you interested in - while you are in the editor, you will see its source.

Comment: I downloaded source but, when I do like on IBM's link and select node  Source Attachment, can't click on Edit button because it's grayed. Beside node it's written: "Source Attachment: (None) - non modifiable."

Answer (score 1):

right click the class you want to see its implementation in eclipse, and click **"Open Declaration F3"**

Comment: It gives me: "Source not found", and some text below.